# C# Prompt for open/save zip in ASP receiving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

Let me start off by saying I'm sure this is something that's quite simple, unfortunately I just can't seem to figure it out. So here's my problem, I query the database, return what I need, zip it all up, and prompt user to save. When the prompt appears, it appears with the System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Zip file name. When You attempt to open this, it says the file is invalid. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
if (e.CommandName == "DownloadAttachment")
    {
        e.Canceled = true;
        // Create a zip and send it to the client.
        //Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Details saved successfully')</script>");
        var item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        fileId = (int)item.GetDataKeyValue("Unique");
        FileData[] allrecords = null;
        using (
            SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PtcDbModelEntities"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select Unique1, BinaryData, FileName from PtcDbTracker.dbo.CafFileTable where Unique1=@fileId AND FileName IS NOT NULL", conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fileId", fileId));
                conn.Open();
                using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var list = new List<FileData>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new FileData { Unique1 = reader.GetInt32(0) });
                        long len = reader.GetBytes(1, 0, null, 0, 0);
                        Byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                        list.Add(new FileData { BinaryData = (byte)reader.GetBytes(1, 0, buffer, 0, (int)len), FileName = reader.GetString(2) });
                        allrecords = list.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Create an archive and store the stream in memory.

            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
            {
                if (allrecords != null)
                {
                    foreach (var record in allrecords)
                    {
                        //Create a zip entry for each attachment
                        if (record.FileName != null)
                        {

                            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(record.FileName);

                            //Get the stream of the attachment
                            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(record.BinaryData))
                            {
                                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                                {
                                    //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.BinaryWrite(compressedFileStream.ToArray());
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=result.zip");
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
                zipArchive.Dispose();
                //How Do I Prompt for open or save?
            }
        }
```

edit: included Sami's suggestion. Zip Folder now saves and opens, but does not have any content.

Comment: Can you please clarify what help you are looking for - file name (not sure if it is a problem, sounds like you know why/expect the behavior), file corruption (seem to be expected too as you don't write anything to output) or "How Do I Prompt for open or save?" (or maybe something different altogether).

Comment: Sorry Alexei, I have been kind of cast into this position, so every piece of code I end up writing is always a new adventure. I know the response.appendheader will prompt for the open/save dialog. How do I put in the zip into the output stream so that I can successfully download the zip file I have created, and how do I give the file a proper name?

Comment: Each of the problem you've mentioned have multiple answers on SO already... If you scope your post down to one single problem at a time someone may provide answer or search for duplicate links for you. So far feels too broad.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I understand your frustration, and I have searched. I don't like posting if I don't have to, I don't want to feel like others are doing my job. I have made edits into the original post. Now my problem appears to be there is nothing in the folder, despite stepping through and it appearing as though it writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the correct `Content-Disposition` header, but for the filename you just append the object, so the platform calls `ToString()` on it and by default it will output the class name. You probably want to send either a random filename, or a static one.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=result.zip");
```

Then for the sending of the file. You use a `MemoryStream` to save the zip archive and you don't send it. One way to do it would be

```
Response.BinaryWrite(compressedFileStream.ToArray());
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Comment: I have made the edits (See OP). Now the folder opens, only with no content.

Comment: @MatthewDetweiler If you have another question, please post it as a separate question and don't edit the original post/code, since then the answers will not be in sync with the current question.